# iPad Mapkit and Conical Projections

Tags: mapkit, ipad

I read in the iPad mapkit is designed to use Mercator projection maps.

It is possible to use this interface with Lambert Conical Projection maps?

Answer (score 1):

The Mercator style used is the same as Google Maps, Bing Maps etc. and is currently the only one supported by mapKit. Lambert Conical Projection is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to get the images in a Mercator format (specifically the EPSG:3785 (3857 as of February) standard), you could try re-projecting the images on the fly. It's not too slow in my testing on a 3GS (Equirectangular to Mercator), but I'm losing some image quality (acceptable in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write  your own for Lambert. If your maps are GEO encoded, then it is doable. I have apps that display GEO encoded Lamberts. It takes a bit of effort. Especially, if you need to display a mosaic.